# gparted error details when partitioning

Tags: partitioning, gparted, ext3

```
GParted 0.25.0 --enable-libparted-dmraid --enable-online-resize

Libparted 3.2
Create Primary Partition #1 (ext3, 119.24 GiB) on /dev/sdb  00:02:45    ( ERROR )

create empty partition  00:00:16    ( SUCCESS )
```

`path: /dev/sdb1 (partition)
start: 2048
end: 250068991
size: 250066944 (119.24 GiB)
clear old file system signatures in /dev/sdb1  00:00:12    ( SUCCESS )`

`write 512.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 0  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
write 4.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 67108864  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
write 512.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 128033751040  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
write 4.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 128034209792  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
write 8.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 128034267136  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
flush operating system cache of /dev/sdb  00:00:06    ( SUCCESS )
set partition type on /dev/sdb1  00:00:12    ( SUCCESS )`

`new partition type: ext3
create new ext3 file system  00:02:05    ( ERROR )`

`mkfs.ext3 -F -L "" /dev/sdb1  00:02:05    ( ERROR )`

```
Discarding device blocks: failed - Input/output error
Creating filesystem with 31258368 4k blocks and 7815168 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 495c08bd-fe1e-4287-8273-d29541964640
Superblock backups stored on blocks:
32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208,
4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872
```

`Allocating group tables: done
Writing inode tables: done
Creating journal (32768 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: 0/954
mke2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)`

`Warning, had trouble writing out superblocks.
libparted messages    ( INFO )`

`Input/output error during read on /dev/sdb
The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.
Input/output error during write on /dev/sdb
Input/output error during write on /dev/sdb
Input/output error during read on /dev/sdb
The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.
Input/output error during write on /dev/sdb
Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sdb: Input/output error
Input/output error during read on /dev/sdb
The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.
Input/output error during write on /dev/sdb
Input/output error during write on /dev/sdb`

========================================

Comment: It is saying you have corrupt gpt partition tables. I prefer gpt as it has both a primary & backup where MBR, just has one. Do you want gpt or MBR? You may have to repair gpt or erase it first. http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html

Answer (score 0):

After trying too many things like.

Failed: Tried to format in OS X Disk utility.
Failed: Tried to format in windows 10
Failed: Tried to change to MBR

always returned error of input/output error.

So, the way that finally worked:
1. Download Ubuntu ISO
2. Execute Startup Disk Creator and load the ISO into the troubled HDD
3. boot from the new bootable HDD.

Hope it works for you, it helped to recover, reformat and finally become a usable disk.